# Voltage between phases of 220V 3-Phase Generator with no neutral

Tags: voltage, three-phase

I'm looking at a 220V-50Hz 3phase generator which has no neutral wire and 3 live wires.

Am I correct in assuming that the voltage between phases will be 220V for this generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I correct in assuming that the voltage between phases will be 220 V for this generator?

Yes. If there is no neutral then there is nowhere to reference a phase voltage from except one of the other phases.

Note 'V' for volt. 'Hz' for hertz. Units named after a person have their symbols capitalised but are lowercase when spelled out.